# Rolling time series data: Nan issue

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, moving-average

I have a time series data set which I'm not handling very well at the moment.

The plot has improved, but it still doesn't use the label space well.. So for now I share the plot without it as i want to tackle the visualization issue a little later..

Plot of the time series data:

[image]

Code:

```
dir = sorted(glob.glob("bsrn_txt_0100/*.txt"))
gen_raw = (pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', encoding = "utf-8") for file in dir)
gen = pd.concat(gen_raw, ignore_index=True)
gen.drop(gen.columns[[1,2]], axis=1, inplace=True)

#gen['Date/Time'] = gen['Date/Time'][11:] -> cause error, didnt work
filter = gen[gen['Date/Time'].str.endswith('00') | gen['Date/Time'].str.endswith('30')]
filter['rad_tot'] = filter['Direct radiation [W/m**2]'] + filter['Diffuse radiation [W/m**2]']
filter['Date/Time'] = filter['Date/Time'].str.replace('T', ' ')
filter['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(filter['Date/Time'])

df = filter.filter(['Date/Time', 'rad_tot']).copy()
df = df.set_index('Date/Time')
print(df)
plot_df = df.rolling(window=12).mean().fillna(0)
print(plot_df)
plot_df.plot()
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

Current Issue:

- Apparently the first 10 or so rad_tot values' moving average shouldn't be Nan or 0. Isn't it ?

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to do - do not just provide a link to the tutorial you are following, detail what is the step you are having trouble with. Describe what you have tried, what you are getting and what you want to get.

Comment: df.rolling(window=12).mean().fillna(0). This command says "use 12 values to compute a mean, when there is an na replace it with 0" - there are only 5 values in the first 5 rows, so the mean will be na. You can either change this to use rolling(window=12,min_period=1).mean() which will give you the cumulative rolling mean up to the 12th value, or you can not fillna(). It is problem-specific as to which option you choose.

Comment: There should be `0` as you wrote `.fillna(0)`... see @Fredz0r [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48991811/3941704) for explanations

Comment: Im aware what .fillna(0) does

Comment: I see. So I didnt fully understand how the moving average function worked.. since the window is set at 12, until the 12th term where the window is full there is no value to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
plot_df=df.rolling(window=12).mean()
```

this gives you the mean of the last 12 points. Because for the first 11 values this can't be computed these yield a 'na'.

```
plot_df.fillna(0)
```

This replaces the na's by 0.

You could also remove the first 11 values from your dataframe so that you don't get whitespace on the left.

```
plot_df[:10].plot()
```

or you calculate the rolling average and ignore na values in your plot to get rid of the whitespace on the left and right:

```
df=df.rolling(window=12).mean()
df.dropna().plot()
```